R st_nearest_point returning linestring not touching second geometry
I'm using the st_nearest_point function to find the closest spot on a line to a nearby point. I am not sure what the issue is, but I cannot get the function to return a linestring with any point touching the line. I need to use the 4326 crs because that is what leaflet maps use and in my real application my starting point is a map_click capture. st_nearest_point returns a linestring that is close but not touching the line. What gives? Please see example below.
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(mapview)

#Creating some dummy data to test with
# Create a line object (LINESTRING)
line <- st_sfc(st_linestring(matrix(c(-122.4, 37.7, -122.5, 37.8), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)), crs = 4326)
# Create a point object (POINT) that is close to but does not touch the line
point <- st_sfc(st_point(c(-122.45, 37.78)), crs = 4326)
# Create sf objects
line_sf <- st_sf(geometry = line)
point_sf <- st_sf(geometry = point)


#Plotting the objects so you can see they don't touch
plot(st_geometry(line_sf), col = 'blue', lwd = 2)
plot(st_geometry(point_sf), col = 'red', add = TRUE)

#Confirming with st_touches
st_touches(line_sf,point_sf)


#Lets find the closest point on the line and use that

geo <- st_nearest_points(point_sf, line_sf)
lngs = geo |> st_length() # Next few lines are redundant here but important if there are multiple lines
nearestp = min(lngs)
my_linestring <- geo[nearestp == lngs]
new_point <- st_cast(my_linestring, 'POINT')[c(FALSE,TRUE)] |> st_as_sf()


#Now lets plot this new point   
plot(st_geometry(line_sf), col = 'blue', lwd = 2)
plot(st_geometry(point_sf), col = 'red', add = TRUE)
plot(st_geometry(new_point), col = 'green', add = TRUE)

#Success? Not so fast lets confirm with st_touches

st_touches(line_sf,new_point)

#Lets use mapview to see if we can see by zooming in the farthest we can

mapview(line_sf) + mapview(new_point, col.region  = "green") + mapview(point_sf, col.region  = "red")

#Looks good but if you zoom in you will see the points indeed do not touch. 



What gives?

This is probably a shortcoming of floating point arithmetic as discussed here: https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1503
There is a workaround using sfnetworks
https://luukvdmeer.github.io/sfnetworks/articles/sfn03_join_filter.html#blending-points-into-a-network
That's the approach taken in the code below. While the point does end up on the line, st_touches() still returns false or empty.
library(sfnetworks)

#blend the line & points into an sf_newtork
blended <- st_network_blend(as_sfnetwork(line_sf), new_point)
#select the edges & return a linestring
line_n <- blended %>% activate('edges') %>% st_as_sf() %>% st_union() %>% st_as_sf() %>% st_cast('LINESTRING')
# select the nodes & return as points
points_n <- blended %>% activate("nodes") %>% st_as_sf() %>% st_combine() %>% st_as_sf() %>% st_cast('POINT')
point_n <- points_n[3,] #just picking the right point (not the end nodes)

mapview(line_n) + mapview(points_n, col.region = 'green') + mapview(point_n, col.region = 'red')


st_touches(line_n, point_n)
#Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 1, where the predicate was #`touches'
# 1: (empty)


Much thanks. I'm already working with sfnetworks in my real application so this is a good fix. The key in my case was to use line_n instead of the original line work line_sf.

I don't believe you can use st_touches() in this exact scenario because of how "touches" predicate is defined ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM ):

A touches B: they have at least one point in common, but their interiors do not intersect.
LineString

interior: points that are left when the boundary points are removed.
boundary: two end points



In other words, point can only touch line's endpoints. Perhaps evaluate intersect instead?
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.12.1, GDAL 3.8.4, PROJ 9.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
l  <- st_as_sfc("LINESTRING (0 0, 1 1, 2 0)")
p0 <- st_as_sfc("POINT (0 0)")
p1 <- st_as_sfc("POINT (1 1)")

              # 1, 2G, 3R 
st_touches(   c(l, p0, p1), sparse = FALSE)
#>       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
#> [1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#> [2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#> [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
# only p0 touches
st_intersects(c(l, p0, p1), sparse = FALSE)
#>      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
#> [1,] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#> [2,] TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#> [3,] TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# both points intersect
plot(c(l, p0, p1), col = c("darkblue", "darkgreen", "darkred"), pch = 16, cex = 2, axes = TRUE)


Created on 2024-09-14 with reprex v2.1.1

Thank you. Yes I should have been testing with st_intersection.

library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.12.0, GDAL 3.7.1, PROJ 9.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

Make sure sf_use_s2() is set to TRUE
sf::sf_use_s2(TRUE)

line <- st_sfc(st_linestring(matrix(c(-122.4, 37.7, -122.5, 37.8), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)), crs = 4326)
point <- st_sfc(st_point(c(-122.45, 37.78)), crs = 4326)
line_sf <- st_sf(geometry = line)
point_sf <- st_sf(geometry = point)

geo <- st_nearest_points(point_sf, line_sf) |>
  sf::st_sf()

In this case st_nearest_points() returns a shortest linestring between point_sf and line_sf, no need to sort it:
geo
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -122.4684 ymin: 37.76848 xmax: -122.45 ymax: 37.78
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>   st_nearest_points.point_sf..line_sf.
#> 1       LINESTRING (-122.45 37.78, ...

Both lines intersects:
sf::st_intersects(line_sf, geo)
#> Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 1, where the predicate
#> was `intersects'
#>  1: 1

And the requested new_point is an intersection itself:
new_point <- st_intersection(line_sf, geo)

tmap::tmap_mode("view")
#> tmap mode set to 'view'
tmap::tm_shape(line_sf) +
  tmap::tm_lines(col = "blue") +
  tmap::tm_shape(point_sf) +
  tmap::tm_dots(size = 0.5) +
  tmap::tm_shape(geo) +
  tmap::tm_lines(col = "green") +
  tmap::tm_shape(new_point) +
  tmap::tm_dots(col = "green", size = 1, shape = 12)

However, while projecting longitude and latitude to X, Y coordinates, the line_sf is projected as straight line between start and end points, not a curve. Therefore new_point is placed a bit out of line.

I would convert the coordinates to any projected CRS, do the calculations and if needed, convert it back to lat/lon.
Created on 2024-09-14 with reprex v2.1.0

Interesting. I checked and I already had sf_use_s2() set to TRUE. Your code works for me but I need to refine geo to a point. Using new_point <- st_intersection(line_sf, geo) and then calling st_intersection(line_sf, new_point) I get a feature of zero length.

In addition to the inaccuracies inherent to floating point math consider how lines defined by their start and end coordinates only are represented on your map (straight lines) and in on a sphere (great circles). The S2 backend used in {sf} for working with unprojected coordinates uses the great circle method.
To give it a more concrete example: if we densify your line_sf object by adding some extra vertices we get a line that matches the location of your point much more closely, but is no longer "straight" but slightly curved.
line_sf_alt <-  st_segmentize(line_sf, 5000)

mapview(line_sf, color = "black") +      # original line in black 
  mapview(line_sf_alt, color = "blue") + # alternative line in blue
  mapview(new_point, col.region  = "green") + mapview(point_sf, col.region  = "red")



